# OpenCL global work-offset implies performance hit?

Tags: performance, opencl

I have a kernel that processes a large image (OpenCL 1.1, data type is image2d_t). Sometimes I only want to process a region of this image. The obvious solution is to use a global work-offset. I would expect this to yield a performance gain, but so far I only get *worse* execution time with non-zero offsets!

```
// Image is 4096x4096 pixels. Local work size is 8x8.
//
// Example A:
globalWorkSize = { 4096, 4096 };
globalWorkOffset = { 0, 0 };
// Execution time is 38 seconds
//    
// Example B:
globalWorkSize = { 3296, 3296 };
globalWorkOffset = { 400, 400 };
// Execution time is 58 seconds <------------------ ?!
//
// Example C: Cropped image @ 3296x3296 pixels
globalWorkSize = { 3296, 3296 };
globalWorkOffset = { 0, 0 };
// Execution time is 28 seconds
```

Can somebody please explain why I get these results?

Comment: Can we see your kernel (not necessarily all of it but the input, output, general structure with loops etc...)? There isn't much to go on here.

Comment: I'll try to make a minimum sample that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Have you tried with offsets aligned to 64? Anything unaligned can kill GPU performance.

Comment: Very interesting! Will try that.

Comment: Do you have access to assembly for the CL kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Lubo Antonov is right about data access alignment being important for performance. But another parameter is accessing memory in strided pattern.

Example of yours with starting from x=400 and y=400 is:

```
. = item
x = work item
c = memory channel
stride = 4096 between y_item=1 and y_item=2 and in this stride, 
some of memory channels are left in "." areas and unused

  unused channel
  ^
  | 
  c c c c c c c c c c
  . . . . . . . . . . 
  . x x x x x x x x x
  . x x x x x x x x x
  . x x x x x x x x x
  . x x x x x x x x x
  . x x x x x x x x x
  . x x x x x x x x x
  . x x x x x x x x x
  . x x x x x x x x x
  . x x x x x x x x x
```

ofcourse there are more channels in first 400 unused pixels but some of those channels are less in numbers than other channels in "x" working areas. Example, channel 2,3,4,5,6,7 are 20 times accessed in "x" but channel 1 is accessed for 25 times which forces a more serialized access to it than other channels.

a hight power-of-2 strided memory access use less memory channels/banks and decrease performance if strided area has different number of memory channels than non-strided area.

---

Advantage of Z-ordering support of hardware for performance also could have been broken at the left edge of work area.

---

If each scanline is not an exact multiple of number of compute units in a gpu, a same compute unit may not get cached data from last scanline in L1 cache(remember Z-ordering access and neighbour-accesses for things like a Gaussian Filter)

```
   c = compute unit, S=selected compute unit for observation
   kernel is accessing neighbour pixels too, for filtering, for example

   gpu has 10 compute units   

   strided: L1 cache not hit
   ..........
   .cccSccccc
   .ccccScccc
   .cccccSccc
   .ccccccScc
   .cccccccSc
   .ccccccccS

   non-strided: pixel[y-1] is already in L1, cache hit, more performance
   ..........
   cccScccccc
   cccScccccc
   cccScccccc
   cccScccccc
   cccScccccc
```

but this is not guaranteed, just an instinct about workitems are distributed for maximum core occupation where every core of gpu is loaded equally through iterative work distribution instead of this: filling first then filling second then filling third, etc.... Filling first core would be good for that core efficiency but leaving other cores unoccupied would break advantage of having more cores imho. Also this would require a long range filtering kernel. 5x5 filter would benefit from only edge pixels while 51x51 filter would include several workgroups.

Answer (score 1):

Although using images seems to be the right choice it might not be the case always.

If you do not need interpolation between pixels and no need for border colour handling then it might be better to use buffers over images.

Even when you have boarder colours to deal with you can have separate kernels dealing with edge regions and buffers might give good performance overall better performance.

The reason for getting better performance with images comes from ability load more than one pixel at a time from memory, in some architectures instructions could load 128bits at a time.

And coming to actual question,
My guess is hw does compute the actual coordinates for each pixel using offset and work id.